# Child take width % from parents parent

Tags: css

Is the following result possible with CSS: [image]

So that li.item takes 50% of the width of div.wrapper, not the ul.list (which is extremly long).
I've added a snippet of a basic setup. Any ideas on the matter are appreciated (please keep in mind I'm looking for CSS options). A jsfiddle playground link: http://jsfiddle.net/6o8t9t8L/

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.list {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 2000px;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item"></li>
        <li class="item"></li>
        <li class="item"></li>
        <li class="item"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/6o8t9t8L/7/

Comment: li.item will have a width of 1000 instead of 50 as expected

Answer (score 6):

I believe there are some '**workaround**' solutions to your issue, so I'll pour in some of my ideas, maybe it will help you out a bit.

**Idea 1: Position absolute and a bunch of :nth-child selectors**

In order to make the `.item` have their width relative to `.list` wrapper, you can absolute position these items, and set `.list` wrapper to position relative, so that the `.item` width will be calculated based on `.list` width.

The **major downfall** of this idea would be that you have to position these elements next to each, like using the `left` property, but passing it like a loop:

- first item will have left: 0;
- second item will have left: 50%;
- third item will have left: 100%;
- and so on...+50% to the next items

You can either pour in a bunch of :nth-child(n), each with +50% left prop. from each other, **OR** use some **sass** stuff to make it faster.

Check out the **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/x3hmqLdb/1/)** & **[sass demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoEgbp)**

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*make the grandparent, .wrapper, relative, so that the grandchilds, .item, 
    will calculate their width based on this width*/
  position: relative;
}
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 2000px;
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*since everyone has position absolute, theres no content flow, so a fixed height
    has to be supplied*/
  height: 200px;
}
.item {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  /*you can set a height here, or position them like I did bellow*/
  top: 51px;
  bottom: 51px;
}
/*now the fun part starts
somehow these .items have to have left: +50% for each of them, like a loop somehow,
so you can either pour in a lot of nth-child(), for how many children you think this
list is going to have, or use sass to write it faster like i did here: 
*/

.item:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  left: 50%;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  left: 100%;
}
.item:nth-child(4) {
  left: 150%;
}
.item:nth-child(5) {
  left: 200%;
}
.item:nth-child(6) {
  left: 250%;
}
.item:nth-child(7) {
  left: 300%;
}
.item:nth-child(8) {
  left: 350%;
}
.item:nth-child(9) {
  left: 400%;
}
.item:nth-child(10) {
  left: 450%;
}
.item:nth-child(11) {
  left: 500%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Idea 2: Display: flex**

Using `display: flex` on `.wrapper`, will allow you to have the widths of the `.item` to be relative to their grandparent.

The **major downfall** of this idea would be that the width of `.list` element, will be overwritten by the width of `.wrapper`, no matter if you specify it or not. **However**, not all is lost, if you need that specific width for some styling, you can specify it, and use some pseudo classes with `width: inherit`, so they'll stretch to whatever width you specified in the first place.

Check out the [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9qkwkzf2/)

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  /*bring on the awesomeness*/
  margin: 20px;
}
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  /*you can keep this defined width, items will calculte their width
    based on .wrapper class, wich will overwrite this classes width,
    however if you have some use for this width, consider using :after, :before
    classes like I did bellow, with .list:before*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 2000px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  /*display inline block extra spacing ....*/
}
.list:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: inherit;
  /*it will inherit the width you set above*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  font-size: 16px;
  /*bump back the font-size*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">a</li>
    <li class="item">b</li>
    <li class="item">c</li>
    <li class="item">d</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your flex answer is great! Where/how did you discern that `display: flex on .wrapper, will allow you to have the widths of the .item to be relative to their grandparent`?  Is there anyway for list to have display: flex so items' order can be easily adjusted via css?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item"></li>
        <li class="item"></li>
        <li class="item"></li>
        <li class="item"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.list {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    white-space:nowrap; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 47%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 1%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btsewL9v/
I would suggest something like this..

**EDIT:**
I don't know how many items you are trying to cram into the list, but take a look at this:
http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/