# Why does parent::before {width: inherit; position: absolute} let child specify the % width of the grandparent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone please explain to me why the solution to the following problem works?

Problem:
Make the child div's width 100% to its grandparent's width, while the parent's width is much wider.

Solution:
Set grandparent `display: flex`,
Set `parent::before {content: ""; width: inherit; position: absolute;}`
Set child `width: 100%`.

The described solution is great, compared to position: absolute directly on child, because there is no need to tinker with the top alignment etc.

See answer and fiddle by RGLSV:
[Child take width % from parents parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906379/child-take-width-from-parents-parent/27909484)

http://jsfiddle.net/9qkwkzf2/

Here is the tab slider I build with this solution, if someone is interested:

```js
            const tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-btn");
            const tabContent = document.querySelector(".tab-content");

            tabButtons.forEach((btn, i) => {
                tabButtons[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
                    document
                        .querySelector(".tab-btn.active")
                        .classList.remove("active");
                    tabButtons[i].classList.add("active");
                    tabContent.style.marginLeft = `calc(-${i}*100%`;
                });
            });
```

```css
           * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                min-height: 100vh;
                background: #222;
                color: #f2f2f2;
            }
            .tabs-container {
                width: 500px;
                height: 200px;
                background: #f2f2f2;
                color: rgb(21, 105, 153);
            }
            .tabs {
                display: grid;
                grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
                grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
                grid-template-areas:
                    "btn-1 btn-2 btn-3 btn-4"
                    "main main main main";
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .tab-btn {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .tab-btn:nth-child(1) {
                grid-area: btn-1;
            }
            .tab-btn:nth-child(2) {
                grid-area: btn-2;
            }
            .tab-btn:nth-child(3) {
                grid-area: btn-3;
            }
            .tab-btn:nth-child(4) {
                grid-area: btn-4;
            }
            .tab-content {
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                width: calc(4 * 100%);
                grid-area: main;
                display: flex;
                transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            }
            .tab-content:before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                width: inherit;
            }
            .tab-content > div {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 1rem;
            }
            .tab-btn {
                border: none;
                padding: 1rem;
                border-radius: inherit;
                background: #dddddd;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            }
            .tab-btn.active {
                background: #f2f2f2;
                transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Tabs</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tabs-container">
            <div class="tabs">
                <button class="tab-btn active">Tab 1</button>
                <button class="tab-btn">Tab 2</button>
                <button class="tab-btn">Tab 3</button>
                <button class="tab-btn">Tab 4</button>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Tab 1</h1>
                        <p>
                            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                            elit. Corrupti facere sit aspernatur itaque? Sed
                            similique libero quis earum neque? Provident rem
                            neque nisi assumenda ducimus itaque, in commodi quas
                            ea illo unde suscipit iste nam voluptates ipsa illum
                            distinctio pariatur!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1>Tab 2</h1>
                        <p>
                            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                            elit. Corrupti facere sit aspernatur itaque? Sed
                            similique libero quis earum neque? Provident rem
                            neque nisi assumenda ducimus itaque, in commodi quas
                            ea illo unde suscipit iste nam voluptates ipsa illum
                            distinctio pariatur!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1>Tab 3</h1>
                        <p>
                            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                            elit. Corrupti facere sit aspernatur itaque? Sed
                            similique libero quis earum neque? Provident rem
                            neque nisi assumenda ducimus itaque, in commodi quas
                            ea illo unde suscipit iste nam voluptates ipsa illum
                            distinctio pariatur!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1>Tab 4</h1>
                        <p>
                            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                            elit. Corrupti facere sit aspernatur itaque? Sed
                            similique libero quis earum neque? Provident rem
                            neque nisi assumenda ducimus itaque, in commodi quas
                            ea illo unde suscipit iste nam voluptates ipsa illum
                            distinctio pariatur!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't think the `::before` style rule is doing anything.  Your snippet behaves exactly the same if I remove it.

Comment: RGLSV explains it perfectly. The specified and computed width setting of the flex item (i.e. the parent div) is totally overridden by the default flex-shrink behaviour . If it wasn't for the ::before pseudo element inheriting the pre-overridden width, it would entirely ignored.

Comment: @PsiKai you are right, I tested it again and it seems to work without `::before`.  I still don't understand the overriding behavior correctly.

Comment: @Alohci Does this mean that when I set something flex it will not pass on its width to child elements? This is why the child `width: 100%` skips the flex parent and moves up to the next higher element with specified width?
My trouble is probably: which width is the `::before`  inheriting? I read that its the first child of the element it was specified on. So does that mean it would inherit `width: calc(4*100%)`, so the parent's width?

Comment: All CSS boxes have a computed width and a used width. The flex item's computed width is 2000px: this is the value that is inherited. But it has a flex-shrink value of 1, which, given that it is the only flex item in the flex container, means that all the negative space (1600px = the difference between 2000px and its container width of 400px)  is assigned to it reducing the used width of its content box to 400px. This is the value that the `width: 50%` refers to meaning that each inline-block is 200px wide.

Comment: @Alohci Thank you for the explanation, I think I understand the behavior much better now!